# How to get the status of storage used by an App programmatically?

Tags: iphone, ios, data-storage

I have an App that stores user data like images and text. I want to show how much disk space is consumed by my App. Is this possible?

Comment: Where are you storing your data? Is it in sqlite file or in NSDocumentsDirectory or using NSFileManager

Answer (score 1):

I dont know all the three, but i have done something to get the size of documents in directory through file manager, may be this will help you, here is the code

```
[[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:path isDirectory:&isDir];
        if (isDir) {
            NSPipe *pipe = [NSPipe pipe];
            NSTask *t = [[[NSTask alloc] init] autorelease];
            [t setLaunchPath:@"/usr/bin/du"];
            [t setArguments:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"-k", @"-d", @"0", path, nil]];
            [t setStandardOutput:pipe];
            [t setStandardError:[NSPipe pipe]];

            [t launch];

            [t waitUntilExit];

            NSString *sizeString = [[[NSString alloc] initWithData:[[pipe fileHandleForReading] availableData] encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding] autorelease];
            sizeString = [[sizeString componentsSeparatedByString:@" "] objectAtIndex:0];
            bytes = [sizeString longLongValue]*1024;
        }
        else {
            bytes = [[[NSFileManager defaultManager] attributesOfItemAtPath:path error:nil] fileSize];
        }
```

bytes will return you the size